# How to sketch $x^2(2/5)^x + (3/5)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I am trying to solve the equation $x^2\cdot2^x + 3^x = 5^x$ in the real numbers. I have trivially found $x=0$, $x=1$ and $x=2$; it is clear that there are no negative solutions. I am trying to prove that there are no other positive solutions, and sketching the function $f(x)=x^2(2/5)^x + (3/5)^x$ would be one way of doing so. Having found the derivative $f'(x)=2x(2/5)^x + x^2(2/5)^x \ln(2/5) + (3/5)^x\ln(3/5)$, however, I am not sure how to proceed.

We know that $f(x)>0$ and that $f(x)=1$ at $x=0,1,2$. What I need to do is show that $f(x)$ has exactly one turning point in each of $0<x<1$ and $1<x<2$.

I am open to seeing other approaches of solving the original equation as well.

Comment: @Moo Of course there is nothing wrong per se, but using a graphical calculator doesn't explain why a graph behaves as it does. (After all, you can barely tell the specifics required with that particular plotting anyway.)

Comment: there is a middle ground: for a real function that is not too much of a mess, I use a programmable calculator to plot points at, say, integer $x$ then maybe at $j/10$ . On graph paper. The same thing for the first and second derivatives, should these be needed. It may be that features of these graphs can be proved rigorously; if not, there is still a better idea of what is going on. In any case, drawing such graphs is a learning experience. It really is

Comment: @Will I understand, and I think it is to no surprise that I have indeed used a graphical calculator already to see the result. I’m not completely satisfied with just taking that for granted though. I’m trying to find some kind of reasoning that explains why there has to be only one turning point in each interval above.

Comment: WolframAlpha shows a plot here for $x^2\cdot2^x + 3^x = 5^x$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%5Ccdot2%5Ex+%2B+3%5Ex+%3D+5%5Ex)

and a different plot for $x^2\cdot2^x + 3^x - 5^x=0$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%5Ccdot2%5Ex+%2B+3%5Ex+-+5%5Ex%3D0)